# Main thread does not await at Task.WhenAll(tasks)

Tags: .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, windows-services

I am trying to implement multithreading in my windows service. I have scheduled tasks depending on various conditions in public static int ProcessScheduledInterfaces(). This method structure is somewhat described below:

```
    protected async void Elapsed_Time(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        await RunDownloadParallelAsync();

        watch.Stop();
        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        resultsWindow.Text += $"Total execution time: { elapsedMs }";
    }

    private List<string> PrepData()
    {
        List<string> output = new List<string>();

        resultsWindow.Text = "";

        output.Add("https://www.yahoo.com");
        output.Add("https://www.google.com");
        output.Add("https://www.microsoft.com");
        output.Add("https://www.cnn.com");
        output.Add("https://www.codeproject.com");
        output.Add("https://www.stackoverflow.com");

        return output;
    }

    
    private async Task RunDownloadParallelAsync()
    {
        List<string> websites = PrepData();
        List<Task<WebsiteDataModel>> tasks = new List<Task<WebsiteDataModel>>();

        foreach (string site in websites)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ProcessJobs.DownloadWebsite(site)));
            //tasks.Add(DownloadWebsiteAsync(site));
        }

        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        //foreach (var item in results)
        //{
        //    ReportWebsiteInfo(item);
        //}
    }
public class ProcessJobs
    {
        public static WebsiteDataModel DownloadWebsite(string websiteURL)
        {
            WebsiteDataModel output = new WebsiteDataModel();
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            output.WebsiteUrl = websiteURL;
            output.WebsiteData = client.DownloadString(websiteURL);

            return output;
        }
    }
    }
```

I have attached image of my code for further clarification.
thanks in advance for the help

Now in this you can imagine having the for loop of the image and
var results = await Task.WhenAll(task) after the for loop;
Please keep in mind i am doing this inside a windows service and Timer_elapsed is called every 5 minutes. I am awaiting my RunDownloadParallelAync() inside the Timer_Elapsed Event.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the SO. Can you please add code as text? Also there is no `Task.WhenAll(tasks)` call in your picture. And it would be great if you could add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks for showing interest . I have tried creating a somewhat similar logic. Please also read some additional comments i added.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is my execution does not wait at var results = await Task.Run(tasks) for task's completion.

Comment: How do you check that it doesn't wait?

Comment: Hitting f10 while debugging

Comment: Not sure that it is a very good way to check this. Can you add a simple executable reproducer?

Comment: I tried putting a logger inside my action in Task.Run and found that the method is not getting executed. So i guess this is the actual issue. For some unknown reasons Task.Run(() => method()) is not getting executed.

Comment: One more thing i am testing this without installing this service. So will post installation behaviour change??

Comment: I highly doubt it will change after installation.

Comment: I also noticed one thing the same logic is working fine for UI based application but not for console or windows service application. Can you suggest something?

Comment: Which logic for example?

Comment: The code logic i have added in my question is working fine in a wpf application but not in console application.

Comment: Can you post somewhere your full concole application? Or minimal corresponding repro.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. Thanks for your interest and sorry for the late response. 

Comment: Glad you resolved it!